# BufferedReader is not blocking in readLine

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedreader

I'm creating a networked game in Java using the Sockets api, and got the following problem:

When the app starts the server socket starts listening and spawns a new Thread for each new client (basic stuff, doesn't need to show this code).

Then the client starts the conversation, sending the String "LOGIN". The server receives it and responds with "LOGIN_OK". Now the conversation is over, but the console keeps printing LOGIN_OK (which happens on the client).

Why this happens? readLine() is not supposed to block? 
Thanks for any clarification!

EDIT: The problem was in the client loop. The client is sending the server's response back to the server! Just commented out that line solved it!

### Server loop

```
public void run()
    {
        String fromClient = null;

        try {
            while ((fromClient = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(fromClient);
                String response = SessionProtocol.handleInput(fromClient);

                out.println(response);
                Thread.sleep(50L);
            }

        } catch(IOException ex){ex.printStackTrace();}  
          catch(InterruptedException ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
    }
```

### Client loop

```
public void run()
    {
        String fromServer = null;

        try {
            while ((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(fromServer);
                String response = SessionProtocol.handleInput(fromServer);
                 // next line causes the problem
                //out.println(response);
                Thread.sleep(50L);
            }

        } catch(IOException ex){ex.printStackTrace();}  
          catch(InterruptedException ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
    }
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, check out ZeroMQ, a Java sockets library; it's a better fit for what you're doing, instead of using plain Java sockets: https://github.com/zeromq/jeromq

Comment: Thanks, i'll definitely check this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `readLine()` is blocking.

Your `in.readLine()` reads until the next `\n` character, regardless of if there's any text before it or not. Since you're calling `out.println()`, you're appending a `\n` to your output, regardless of if response is empty or not.

Thus, each iteration of the loop on both the client and server receive a newline and output a newline, which is why it seems like it's not blocking.

Comment: It outputs "LOGIN_OK", not a new line.

Comment: Right, but you're using `out.println()` which appends a newline to anything you output. Use `out.print()` if you don't want it to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `out.println()` writes the message to the output stream of the communication socket it seems you have 2 problems:

1. Client and server send each other messages continuously, i.e. each loop iteration ends with `out.println(response)`.
2. Check the logic in case `SessionProtocol.handleInput()` on the client receives 'LOGIN_OK'. Is it an empty message or some other message? Same check must be done for the server part. You might be sending `LOGIN/LOGIN_OK` message continuously..

Comment: I'm too stupid. The problem was in the client loop...the client is sending the server's response back to the server! Just commented out that line solved it! Thanks for your help.